# Multihilo termina después de la condición de parada. ¿Es porque no está sincronizado?

Tags: java

multihilo termina con 11, Mientras le decía que terminara a las 10. ¿Por qué? Porque no es sincronizado ?

```
class ThreadTest extends Test{
    public static int globale = 0;
    public final Object monitor;

    public void run(){
        while (global<10){
            synchronized(monitor){
                globale++;
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        ThreadTest t1 = new ThreadTest;
        ThreadTest t2 = new ThreadTest;
        t1.start; t2.start;
        t1.join(); t2.join();
        System.out.println(Thread.globale); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Tienes `public static int globale = 0;` y `globale++;` pero en el `while (global<10)`, ¿no debería de ser `while (globale<10)` **global -> globale**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero aseguremos un concepto. Cuando un hilo entra dentro del bloque `synchronized` activa un semáforo que para a otros hilos hasta que sale del bloque y desactiva el semáforo. Por lo que el hilo bloqueado se queda parado en `synchronized` hasta que pueda continuar

```
synchronized(monitor){
            globale++;
}
```

Ahora imaginemos las ultimas iteraciones.

1. El contador global esta a 9. Llegan casi a la vez los hilos 1 y 2.
2. Como es sincrono, el hilo 1 entra, dejando el hilo 2 a la espera en el `synchronized`
3. El hilo 1 termina el bloque sincrono y como global es >= 10, el bucle termina y se destruye el hilo 1.
4. El hilo 2 puede continuar ya que se ha liberado el código sincrono. Por lo que incrementa el valor de global y este llega a 11.

Esta sería la explicacion de por que te devuelve 11 cuando deberia de ser 10.

Se podria solucionar de la siguiente forma:

```
synchronized(monitor){
    if(globale<10)
    {
        globale++;
    }
}
```